# Do electronics bought airside have to be fully charged?

Tags: usa, electronic-items, duty-free

With the recent regulations concerning electronic devices having to be charged, to take them on the plane, I'm wondering, do you also have to do this with electronics bought airside at the airport, which would presumably have very little charge when taken out of the box for the first time?
Or do they get wrapped in a special bag like liquids do?

Comment: I believe the rule is they need to be charged to take them through security. If you buy them after security, this is not an issue. However, if you have a connection that might require you to clear security again, you should plan how to charge them before that time.

Comment: Comment only: Yet another rule to guard against honest and everyday people. This "test" is so easily fudged that it is of no deterrence whatsoever to any "bad guys" who are aware of it in advance.

Answer (score 3):

While it doesn’t specify if it must be **fully** charged

**TSA** said:

> As the traveling public knows, all electronic devices are screened by
>   security officers. During the security examination, officers may also
>   ask that owners power up some devices, including cell phones.
>   Powerless devices will not be permitted onboard the aircraft. The
>   traveler may also undergo additional screening.

It must at least turn on, so if you buy a new electronic device if it can turn on there should not be a problem, of course as always it depends on the security guard.

But as Gregory says if you bought after the security check there shouldn’t be a problem

Comment: Also I'm guessing that if it's still sealed in its original packaging you should be OK.

Comment: Back in the pre-9/11 era I took a laptop through security with a very bad battery pack--it would die soon after the POST was completed.  I warned the agent what would happen, he accepted seeing it start the boot process and then die.  (I was only using it plugged in, the useless battery wasn't worth replacing.)  It's possible they are more strict now, though.